TOC alignment in the report document class with the appendix package
The following code forces the appendix within the last document part. Adjusting the structure of the appendices up one level to start with part's breaks the appendix all together.
Is there any way to configure the appendix to align with the outermost level parallel to part's?
\documentclass[letterpaper]{report}

\usepackage[sfdefault]{roboto}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[left=0.5in,right=0.5in,top=0.5in,bottom=0.65in]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{ipsum}
\usepackage[skip=1em, indent=0pt]{parskip}

\begin{document}
\part{Part I}
\chapter{Chapter I}
\section{Section I}
\ipsum
\part{Part 2}
\chapter{Chapter 2}
\section{Section 2}
\ipsum
\begin{appendices}
  \chapter{Some Note}
  \section{Section A}
  \ipsum
  \section{Section B}
  \ipsum
  \chapter{Another Note}
  \section{Section A}
  \ipsum
  \section{Section B}
  \ipsum
\end{appendices}
\end{document}



It's the bookmarks, not the table of contents.

You can avoid the command \bookmarksetupnext{level=part} before \begin{appendices} by using \AddToHook{env/appendices/before}{\bookmarksetupnext{level=part}} in the document preamble.

@egreg You are right, I mistakenly referred to the bookmarks as the TOC and hence I missed the existing solutions. Your solution with just a change in the preamble worked perfectly, thank you.

You're welcome! Maybe you can also vote yourself for closing as duplicate.
